# restfull multiple files download

Tags: javascript, java, file, download, jax-rs

I need to proivde multiple files to the client side in one call, i don't want to put those files in a zip.
Files sent to the client are small size, just few ko.
I use JAX-RS for restfull services, and the client uses javascript to process the response.
should i send it  as files or as streams, my files are thumbnails, my clients are mobile devices, and they need those pictures to display them.

I already provide an URL to get a single file :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadFile(String fileName) {
    File file = ... // Find your file
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
        .build();
}
```

Can i sent a List of files Response.ok(myList), and can the client process the reponse constructed that way?

Comment: What about returning a list of Base64 encoded file contents indexed by the filename as the response?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? i encode the content of the whole files in one base64 encoded file, and for every encoded part i prefix it with the filename base64 encoded also, that's what you mean? If this is it so how i separate between the content of an image and its filename? so the client can decode the whole content and extract the images correctly.

Comment: You return a JSON object with the filename as the keys and the base64 encoded file contents as value. Each entry is one file.

Comment: OK  Thomas.mc.work i got it, thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that! I just added it as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a list of Base64 encoded file contents indexed by the filename as the response.

Example:

```
{
    "file1.txt": "YW55IGNvbnRlbnQ=",
    "file2.txt": ...
}
```